# When I run the code, it says "Error using quiver3 (line 44), V and W must be the same size." How do I resolve this?

Tags: matlab

```
%% Program to plot Ekman spiral
%% Input section
clear all; close all;    
i=sqrt(-1)                   % To make sure i is the complex i    
h=120;                       % Water depth    
nut=.02;                     % (constant) turbulence viscosity    
phi=51;                      % Latitude (deg.)    
rho=1000;                    % Water density    
tauwx=0;                     % Wind shear stress x-direction    
tauwy=1;                     % Wind shear stress y-direction    
tau=tauwx+tauwy*i;           % Shear stress vector     
f=2*7.27e-5*sin(phi*pi/180); % Coriolis coefficient    
dek=sqrt(2*nut/f)            % Ekman depth    
dz=5;                        % Vertical step size    
zek=[-h:dz:0];               % Vertical coordinate    
%% Define some additional matrices for plotting purposes    
xek=zeros(size(zek));            
yek=zeros(size(zek));    
taux=zeros(size(zek));    
tauy=zeros(size(zek));    
taux(end)=tauwx;    
tauy(end)=tauwy;    
%% Solution of Ekman spiral    
s=tau*dek/rho/(1+i)/nut*exp((1+i)/dek*zek);    
uek=real(s);    
vek=imag(s);    
%% Plot results    
figure(1);    
quiver3(xek,yek,zek,uek,vek,0,'linewidth',2);    
hold on    
quiver3(xek,yek,zek,taux,tauy,0,'r','linewidth',2);    
title('Ekman spiral')    
xlabel('u');ylabel('v');    
zlabel('z')    
print('-dpng','ekman.png')    
print('-depsc','ekman.eps')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [ask], and edit your question properly.

Comment: you could resolve the error msg by making V and W the same size. Unstructured "help me debug my matlab code" type questions are likely better suited for Matlab Central.

Comment: I posted it on Matlab Central, also V and W are the same size(1x25 double)

Comment: Hey @Amna, the issue is that the 6th argument in `quiver3` is a scalar.  Try `z = zeros(size(xek));` and replace the `0` by `z`.  You can double-check the sizes by typing `whos` anywhere in the code.